# How to improve precision of object pose estimation solvePnP with two cameras?

Tags: motion, aruco, stereoscopy, opencv-solvepnp, pose

Currently, I am using two cameras to estimate the pose of an object (CharucoBoard).

I have tried solvePnP to get the pose of the CharucoBoard using one camera. However, there is still a linear trend of the back-front translation axis. Therefore, I want to use two cameras in a stereo-setup to achieve higher accuracy.

I still don't know how to implement this idea. My guess is to use the [triangulatePoints](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/dbd/group__triangulation.html#ga211c855276b3084f3bbd8b2d9161dc74) function to get the 3D world coordinates of the object, and then re-input them into [solvePnP](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga549c2075fac14829ff4a58bc931c033d) algorithm, should it work or is there any other suggestion?